# CoreData :NSFetchedResultsController one to many to many to many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I working on app were I using core data and the core data object is is show below:

[image]
Giving theaterName and genreName I want to show the actorsName. Anyone know of a way to build a `NSPredicate` to do that?

Comment: The model seems off.  Movies have theaters,  theaters have movies.  That should be a direct relationship.  Movies have genres, but theaters don't have genres.  (It's not the theatre that's a comedy, it's the movie.)

Comment: @PetahChristian the theater,genre relationship is just of way of classifying the movies of each movie theater

Comment: I understand but it doesn't match the real world relationship.  If someone is looking for a comedy, they would want to see what movies are comedies, not what theaters are comedies.  (A theater may show a movie that's a comedy, but the theater itself isn't a comedy.)  People would want to know what movies are playing at a theatre, but there's no direct relationship.  That's all I'm saying.  You're making a simple request's predicate more complicated, just as this Actors question has to pass through Genres, when the query has nothing to do with Genres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SUBQUERY to build NSPredicates that go deep into "to many" relationships:

```
    // Set predicate
NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(genres, $g, ANY $g.movies.name == %@).@count != 0",  @"Batman vs Superman"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:requestPredicate];
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated example, you'll need nested subqueries like this:

```
 NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(movies, $m, ANY $m.genres.name == %@).@count != 0 AND SUBQUERY(movies, $m, SUBQUERY($m.genres, $g, ANY $g.theaters.name == %@).@count != 0).@count != 0", @"Action", @"Harkins"];
```

Here is a sample Cast entity fetch:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cast" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
// Set predicate
NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(movies, $m, ANY $m.genres.name == %@).@count != 0 AND SUBQUERY(movies, $m, SUBQUERY($m.genres, $g, ANY $g.theaters.name == %@).@count != 0).@count != 0", @"Action", @"Harkins"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:requestPredicate];
// Fetch
NSError *error = nil;
if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
// Check fetched objects
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [aFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
for (Cast *eachCast in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Each Cast name: %@", eachCast.name);
}
```

Just replace @"Action" with the desired Genre name and @"Harkins" with the Theater name.

Here is how I setup the core data model:
[image: Core data model setup]

Comment: Thank you for the solution but in your solution you are querying base on the movie name. In my original question was for example. I have the movie theater name "Seattle" and name of the genre "Sci-Fi". I want to list all the actors of the movies showing in theater with the genre  (seattle/sci-fi).

Comment: Updated my answer based on your example.

Comment: @user2924482 were you able to get the filtered Actors with the nested subqueries?